# Django aggregation of aggregation - Cannot compute Sum is an aggregate

Tags: python, django, orm, aggregate

I'm trying to perform an aggregate of an aggregate, but looks like is not possible (SQL doesn't allow it)

Let's start defining what contains the queryset:

> 1. DW00 2020-01-01 2020-03-31 653.38
> 2. DW00 2020-01-01 2020-03-31 8,346.54
> 3. DW00 2020-04-01 2020-06-30 488.00
> 4. DW00 2020-04-01 2020-06-30 8,346.54
> 5. DW00 2020-07-01 2020-09-30 488.00
> 6. DW00 2020-07-01 2020-09-30 8,390.07
> 7. R00 2020-01-01 2020-03-31 6,877.11
> 8. R00 2020-04-01 2020-06-30 6,877.11
> 9. R00 2020-07-01 2020-09-30 6,877.11

The values are respectively: `condition_type`, `calculation_from`, `calculation_to` and `net`.

Now we want sum the row that have same `condition_type` and same competence period (`calculation_from`, `calculation_to`) this translate to rows **1** and **2** merged together, rows **3** and **4** and finally **5** and **6**.

```py
sap_payments = sap_payments.values('condition_type', 'calculation_from', 'calculation_to') \
        .annotate(competence=Sum('net')) \
        .order_by()
```

This will return another queryset that contains:

> 1. {'competence': Decimal('8999.92'), 'calculation_from': datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 'condition_type': 'DW00', 'calculation_to':
>    datetime.date(2020, 3, 31)}
> 2. {'competence': Decimal('8834.54'), 'calculation_from': datetime.date(2020, 4, 1), 'condition_type': 'DW00', 'calculation_to':
>    datetime.date(2020, 6, 30)}
> 3. {'competence': Decimal('8878.07'), 'calculation_from': datetime.date(2020, 7, 1), 'condition_type': 'DW00', 'calculation_to':
>    datetime.date(2020, 9, 30)}
> 4. {'competence': Decimal('6877.11'), 'calculation_from': datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 'condition_type': 'R00', 'calculation_to':
>    datetime.date(2020, 3, 31)}
> 5. {'competence': Decimal('6877.11'), 'calculation_from': datetime.date(2020, 4, 1), 'condition_type': 'R00', 'calculation_to':
>    datetime.date(2020, 6, 30)}
> 6. {'competence': Decimal('6877.11'), 'calculation_from': datetime.date(2020, 7, 1), 'condition_type': 'R00', 'calculation_to':
>    datetime.date(2020, 9, 30)}

Now we want calculate the days diff between `calculation_from` and `calculation_to` of each competence

```py
sap_payments = sap_payments.annotate(days_diff=ExpressionWrapper(
    F('calculation_to') - F('calculation_from'), output_field=DurationField()))
```

Which simply add a days_diff to the previous queryset:

> 1. {'competence': Decimal('8999.92'), 'days_diff': datetime.timedelta(90), 'calculation_from': datetime.date(2020, 1, 1),
>    'condition_type': 'DW00', 'calculation_to': datetime.date(2020, 3,
>    31)}
> 2. {'competence': Decimal('8834.54'), 'days_diff': datetime.timedelta(90), 'calculation_from': datetime.date(2020, 4, 1),
>    'condition_type': 'DW00', 'calculation_to': datetime.date(2020, 6,
>    30)}
> 3. {'competence': Decimal('8878.07'), 'days_diff': datetime.timedelta(91), 'calculation_from': datetime.date(2020, 7, 1),
>    'condition_type': 'DW00', 'calculation_to': datetime.date(2020, 9,
>    30)}
> 4. {'competence': Decimal('6877.11'), 'days_diff': datetime.timedelta(90), 'calculation_from': datetime.date(2020, 1, 1),
>    'condition_type': 'R00', 'calculation_to': datetime.date(2020, 3, 31)}
> 5. {'competence': Decimal('6877.11'), 'days_diff': datetime.timedelta(90), 'calculation_from': datetime.date(2020, 4, 1),
>    'condition_type': 'R00', 'calculation_to': datetime.date(2020, 6, 30)}
> 6. {'competence': Decimal('6877.11'), 'days_diff': datetime.timedelta(91), 'calculation_from': datetime.date(2020, 7, 1),
>    'condition_type': 'R00', 'calculation_to': datetime.date(2020, 9, 30)}

Now, it's time for aggregate data. We want to sum `competence` and `days_diff` for different `condition_type`.

```py
sap_payments = sap_payments.values('condition_type') \
    .annotate(net_sum=Sum('competence'), days_diff_sum=Sum('days_diff')) \
    .order_by()
```

Which raise the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot compute Sum('competence'): 'competence' is an aggregate
```

How do I achieve what I want?

Comment: You are mixing annotations that do not aggregate, like the `F('calculation_to') - F('calculation_from')`, with annotations that *do* aggregate, like `Sum('days_diff')`. This is not possible in most SQL dialects (if not all).

Comment: This mean I have to perform the aggregation simply using a python loop instead to perform through an SQL query?

Comment: not per se. Exactly *what* do you want to achieve?

Comment: Perform the SUM of columns `competence` and `days_diff` of the 6 rows above.

Comment: So you want to return "one record" basically?

Comment: No, two records. Instead of using `competence` I could use `net` that return the following result. The first row is correct, but the second one is not (because `days_diff` has **542** days intead of **271**.

{'condition_type': 'R00', 'days_diff_sum': datetime.timedelta(271), 'net_sum': Decimal('20631.33')}
{'condition_type': 'DW00', 'days_diff_sum': datetime.timedelta(271), 'net_sum': Decimal('26712.53')}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222587/discussion-between-realnot-and-willem-van-onsem).